# Dart Map keys, get unique key

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary

Simple Map here:

```
Map map = Map<int, String>{};
```

I can populate it:

```
map = {1: 'c', 2: 'dart', 3: 'flutter'};
```

Here I need to specify a KEY. I would like to know on how to get an auto key.

I cannot use map.lenght because whenever I will delete e.g. the second item (2) the third will remain 3 and map.lenght will overwrite that key.

As the @eamirho3ein answer I tried this:

```
  //& Maps
  Map map = <int, Ingredient>{};


Map<int, T> addToMap<T>(Map<int, T> map, T newItem) {
  var list = map.entries.map((e) => e.value).toList();
  list.add(newItem);
  var newIndex = 1;

  return Map.fromIterable(list,
      key: (item) => newIndex++, value: (item) => item);
}


Map<int, Ingredient> result = addToMap<Ingredient>(
                            map, //Error here
                            Ingredient(
                                name: "Pizza",
                                kcal: 100,
                                carbohydrates: 50,
                                proteins: 35,
                                lipids: 23,
                                fibers: 12,
                                date: DateTime.now(),
                                bottomTabIndex: 0,
                                leftTabIndex: 0));
```

But I receive this error on map(indicated):

> The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'Map<int, Ingredient>'.

This is my simple class:

```
class Ingredient {
  String? name;
  int? kcal;
  int? carbohydrates;
  int? proteins;
  int? lipids;
  int? fibers;
  int? leftTabIndex;
  int? bottomTabIndex;
  DateTime? date;

  Ingredient(
      {this.name,
      this.kcal,
      this.carbohydrates,
      this.proteins,
      this.lipids,
      this.fibers,
      this.leftTabIndex,
      this.bottomTabIndex,
      this.date});
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your issue? could you explain more?

Comment: I found a solution that should explain more, please evaluate...

Comment: Why not just use a `List`?

Comment: @jamesdlin maybe the something, however  I'm using Firebase which is map oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function to remove an item in a map and auto generate new key:

```
Map<int, T> removeFromMap<T>(Map<int, T> map, int index) {
    var list = map.entries.map((e) => e.value).toList();
    list.removeAt(index);
    var newIndex = 1;

    return Map.fromIterable(list,
        key: (item) => newIndex++, value: (item) => item);
  }
```

you can use it like this:

```
var result = removeFromMap<String>({1: 'c', 2: 'dart', 3: 'flutter'}, 1);
print("result = $result"); //result = {1: c, 2: flutter}
```

If you want **add** new Item:

```
Map<int, T> addToMap<T>(Map<int, T> map, T newItem) {
    var list = map.entries.map((e) => e.value).toList();
    list.add(newItem);
    var newIndex = 1;

    return Map.fromIterable(list,
        key: (item) => newIndex++, value: (item) => item);
  }
```

and call it like this:

```
var result = addToMap<String>({1: 'c', 2: 'dart', 3: 'flutter'}, 'B');
print("result = $result"); //result = {1: c, 2: dart, 3: flutter, 4: B}
```

Comment: As to understand, you deleted key 1? Then the result should be: //result = {1: dart, 2: flutter} Right?

Comment: no,  It will remove the second Item in map, if you want to remove first one you need pass 0;

Comment: sure, sry. I will try your solution this evening, meanwhile thanks and appears to be the real solution...
Exactly what I'm searching!

Comment: Please, this will work for Map map = Map<int, anyClass>{}; too?

Comment: what do you mean? you mean pass map like this :`addToMap(map, 'c')` ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I have a Class called 'Ingredient' (for cooking purpose, many strings, dates, int), I would like to have this type of Map:
Map map = Map<int, Ingredient>{};
And I would like to know if your functions still work when passing the map to the list and viceversa.

Comment: I updated my answer to use every where.

Comment: Updated my question with the result of your code.

Comment: You need change `var result =`  to `Map<int, Ingredient> result =` , this happened because you define your result variable as dynamic

Comment: Changed code as described, no changes. Error is not in the result but in the map object (somewhere we are trying to access it as <dynamic,dynamic> however I don't find that point...

Comment: try define your map like this: `Map<int, Ingredient> map = {};`

Comment: It's perfect. Nice work

Answer (score 0):

You can use an incrementing `index` key that will be always different than others on every call, and wrapping it inside an `autoKey()` method like this:

```
int index = 0;
autoKey() {
  return ++index;
}

Map<int, String> map = {};
map = {autoKey(): 'c', autoKey(): 'dart', autoKey(): 'flutter'};

print(map); {1: c, 2: dart, 3: flutter}
```

Comment: Yes this will work, however I will need to store the index value too.

Comment: do you need to just set keys, I mean is it important that the keys have different values ?

Comment: Whenever I will save that map to file and load again, my index bell come back to 0 and any other add will not delete items?

Comment: And finally, yes, sorry that I not asked on the main question, I need control over keys as @eamirho3ein answer (because I should now point each key to specific tabs (indexed like map)...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I should use a function:

```
int getNewKey(Map map) {
  if (map.isEmpty) {
    return 0; // or 1, this is the first item I insert
  } else {
    return map.keys.last + 1;
  }
}
```

And use it whenever I will add something to that map:

{getNewKey(map) : 'c', getNewKey(map) : 'dart', getNewKey(map) : 'flutter'}

Please let me know if this is faulty :-|

By this way I will never overwrite a key that's only incremental.

Please note: I should not use directly

```
{(map.keys.last + 1) : 'c', (map.keys.last + 1) : 'dart', (map.keys.last + 1) : 'flutter'}
```

Because if the Map is empty will produce an error.

Comment: this is work if you add, not when you delete an Item.

Comment: Yes, but if I delete items next key will continue to grow (no way to overwrite existing keys)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Map` that uses contiguous, integer-based keys, you should ask yourself if you should be using a `List` instead, and then you don't need to manage keys yourself.

If you must use a `Map` because some API requires it, you can still start with a `List` and then use [`List.asMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/asMap.html) to easily convert it:

```dart
var map = [
    'c',
    'dart',
    'flutter',
  ].asMap();

print(map); // Prints: {0: c, 1: dart, 2: flutter}
```

Note that `List.asMap` returns an *unmodifable* view, so if you want to allow mutation, you would need to create a copy:

```dart
var map = Map.of([
    'c',
    'dart',
    'flutter',
  ].asMap());
```

If must have your `Map` keys be integers starting from 1 and not 0, then you could insert a dummy element (and remove it later if desired):

```dart
var map = Map.of([
    '',
    'c',
    'dart',
    'flutter',
  ].asMap())
    ..remove(0);

print(map); // Prints: {1: c, 2: dart, 3: flutter}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. However as you said we lose control over keys. This should be not a problem for me, but in this case my answer should avoid to pass data to list (at least, I think).

Answer (score -1):

another way is that  you can use a `class` as key that never equals itself using `hashCode`, like this:

```
class nonEqualKey {
  
  @override
  int get hashCode => 0;
  
  @override
  operator ==(covariant nonEqualKey other) {
    return other.hashCode != hashCode;
  }
  @override
  toString() {
    return "unique";
  }
}

Map map = {};
map = {nonEqualKey(): 'c', nonEqualKey(): 'dart', nonEqualKey(): 'flutter'};
print(map); // {unique: c, unique: dart, unique: flutter}
```

Here I overridden the `hashCode` so it will be always `0`, then I overridden the `==` operator so the objects can be equal if they have a different `hashCode` which is impossible since always `0!=0` is `false`.

Even if you use the same `class` constructor, they will never be the same, and so, it lets you use it as much as you want without needing to  handle it for every operation you will do on the `Map`

Comment: 1. Making `hashCode` always return the same value forces all elements to have hash collisions, which makes `Map`/`LinkedHashMap` unnecessarily inefficient. 2. If you want an object to never be equal to anything, you could just override `operator ==` to always return `false` and leave `hashCode` alone. 3. Making an object never be equal to anything (including itself) means that lookups in the `Map` will *always* fail, making it unusable.

Comment: @jamesdlin you're right!